# cant combine text and image into JQuery Dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a picture and text to my JQuery Dialog box yet I am having problems, I'm new to JQuery but can't seem to find anything wrong with the code. Anyone have any ideas on what the problem is ?

```
$(function() {
    $( ".dialog" ).click(function(){   
        $('#dialog').append('<img src="Image here"/><br/>').append($(this).html());
        $('#dialog').html("The Football Game ") + $(this).html() + " Is now playing")dialog({
            resizable:true,
            modal:true,
            height: 350,
            width:  500,
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function()
                {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                },
                "Cancel": function()
                {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Oh wow.. I am not very familar with the jQuery ui dialog. But, your code doesn't make much sense here. You're first appending the image and then overwriting the entire thing with the method html(). Could we please see your HTML too?

Comment: You'll see an immediate difference if you take out the bracket after `"The FootBall Game ") <--------`. Any, check your developers console (F12 in Chrome) because you also have syntax errors (put a `.` before `dialog({`. That'll at least show you things, but you are overwriting your content and you'll need to address that once your dialog works.

Comment: There are a bunch of syntax errors in the question, it's obviously not the real code you're running. But it's hard to advise you when we can't tell what you're really doing. Please paste the code instead of retyping it.

Comment: Hi Barmar, Generally I am trying to get the values from when a cell is clicked in my HTML Table and display it within a JQuery Dialog Box alongside a Picture

Comment: To the owner of the thread; if any of the solutions offered solved your problem do not forget to mark it as the right one so that others with the same or a similar issue can get help through this very thread in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your very example, slightly rewritten.

HTML markup to trigger dialog:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>Here's some content</p>
</div>
<!-- a HTML element with the class "dialog" to trigger the event -->
<input type="button" class="dialog" value="Trigger Dialog"/>
```

Your jQuery example modified:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dialog').click(function(){ //use a better selector to trigger this event..
    var fetchHTML = $('#dialog').html(); //fetch the current HTML of your element with the ID "dialog" and save it within a variable
    $('#dialog').html('<img alt="" src="someimage.png"/>'+ fetchHTML); // add your image to the element and then the HTML that was there before. The method htm() will overwrite everything that was there before

        $('#dialog').dialog({ //use the jquery-ui dialog method with selected parameters
            resizable : true,
            modal : true,
            height : 350,
            width : 500,
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function(){
                       $(this).dialog('close');
                       },
                "Cancel": function(){
                       $(this).dialog('close');
                       }
                }
           });
       });
  });
```

And remember to make sure that you have successfully included:

- jQuery
- jQuery-ui
- jQuery-ui CSS stylesheet (or at least the appropriate classes that you need).

Google hosts them all for you https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide. Easy as pie to just copy and paste them within your document

Whenever developing web applications I use FireFox and have installed extensions such as FireBug, WebDeveloper and YSlow. They're of great help :) Just saying...

Answer (score 1):

### One

The main issue I see is in the line below:

```
$('#dialog').html("The Football Game ") + $(this).html() + " Is now playing")dialog({
```

There is an extra `)` which is closing the `html()` and you are missing a `.` before calling `dialog()`.

```
$('#dialog').html("The Football Game " + $(this).html() + " Is now playing").dialog({
```

### Two

Also, you are calling `html()` *after* `append()`, essentially overwriting the appended content. Try using `append()` after `html()` (or combine all the content into the `html()` call):

```
$('#dialog')
    .html('<img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff"/><br/>')
    .append("The Football Game "+ $(this).html() + " Is now playing")
    .dialog({ ...
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/KL4PT/6/)

Comment: Awesome thanks for the solution, though for some reason in your example the dialog box does not appear formatted correctly !

Comment: I did not include the JQueryUI CSS in my example. [Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/KL4PT/6/).